# array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code that supposed to send post a data in the same page and then push that data into the array.

```
$array = array();
if (isset($_POST["array"])) { 
   $array=unserialize($_POST["array"]);
}
if (isset($_POST["uname"]) && isset($_POST["upass"])) { 
   array_push($array,$nama=$_POST["uname"]+" "+$pass=$_POST["upass"]);
}
print_r($array);

<form action="" method="POST">
username : <input type="text" name="uname">
password : <input type="password" name="upass">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php serialize($array)?>" name="array">
<input type ="submit">
</form>
```

then i get this error:

> array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in

How do i deal with this error?

Comment: try to dump `$array` before pushing

Answer (score -2):

First of all: "unserialize($_POST["array"]);". Do you really post serialized data? 
I think, no and there fore unserialize() returns boolean false and not array. So when you pass it to array_push it says that $array is boolean.

Post your html form where this array is supposed to be filled in. And as asked in the comment above, var_dump($_POST["array"]) will also help.

Comment: i dont know if this what your meaning, but in my code there's a line <input type="hidden" value="<?php serialize($array)?>" name="array">

is this the serialize you talked about? sorry for bad english before i hope this would help you to help me lol

Comment: First, there should be value="<?php echo serialize($array)?>" (add echo). Second, there can be bugs and errors, because serialized string usually contains quotes (") which will be treated by browser as the end of the value. So the whole idea is bad. Third, read the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php. Unserialize returns boolean false when the passed string cannot be unserialized (e.g. corrupt of empty value). I am sure that this is the case.